# How to sort an array with key value(int) pair by its second element's value in descending order?

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

Say I have an array:

```
var array = [ { first: 'qwe123', second: 1234 }, {..}, .. ];
```

I want to sort an array by second keys value(1234) in descending order and put all elements' values into one string. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

- [Array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort
- [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert into an array of integer
- [Array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert the result into a string

The example:

```js
var array = [ {first: 'qwe123', second: 1}, 
             {first: 'qwe123', second: 2}, 
             {first: 'qwe123', second: 3}, 
             {first: 'qwe123', second: 4}];
             
var result = array.sort(function(a, b) {
       return +b.second -  +a.second;
   }).map(function(ele, idx) {
       return ele.second;
   }).join(', ');
             
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i changed it little to return the value of both first and second, anyway thank you very much